# Angular homepage url redirect not correctly

Tags: angular, express, xmlhttprequest

It's weird that the angular app could not redirect from the homepage.

except I have to manually add something after the root '/' . In the picture, it when I start to type `/api/user` into the address bar. Redirection happens then.

It's all XHR hitting the express server when visiting the root URL? when I visit the homepage?

How can I redirect the root domain to the /login?

My router is like this

```
const authUser = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies['connect.sid']) {
        User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.session.user.id
            }
        }).then((user) => {
            if (user && user.status === 'active') {
                next();
            } else {
                res.redirect('/login');
            }
        }).catch(
            () => res.status(500).send("Something wrong!")
        );
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
};

app.get('/login', (req, res, ) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
});
app.all('*', authUser, function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following way, It can be worked

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
```

But you can not redirect from the server If you use .es or .jade then you can redirect.

Now you have to redirect from your angular part

```
this.router.navigate(['/']);
or
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

Comment: Not sure where ths.router line goes? The issue I am having is related to the XHR request hitting the server first for example I need to check that user identity to decide what app state I am going to put the angular into. So the XHR request sent to the server shall be handled to allow the client to make a decision to redirect to the login page. If the user already logged in, should redirect to the business page. The best solution for me is to let the server redirect the client to a URL but because the nature of the app bootstrapping, this doesn't work

Comment: You can not do this res.redirect('/login');, need to write your code to angular part

Answer (score 0):

After quite a few days of pondering what was happening because I don't believe that the browser or angular app are designed in such a weird way of not listening to each other - by that, I mean to agree on HTTP status code to make proper redirection.

The reason why I had this weird redirection happening within the XHR request but not the proper `document` or `html/plain text` type of request is because that the latter was not hitting the `authentication guards` routes at all. So what happened was that the angular was successfully initialized and client was sending XHR request already. So the server missed the chance to send back 302 redirect code to the anguar from the proper channel, yes, via XHR it did, but browser won't response to that.

Why this happened? Because before the guarding routes, I had this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

This is to tell `express.js` to serve static files from the 'dist' folder.

I always thought that this is just configuration, but it is more than that. It actually open up the whole `dist/` and let files be freely downloaded to the browser without problem and the chances to redirect were thus missed completely.

So, after moving this line below the `guarding` routes, all fine.

Now angular initialization was redirected OK as it should. Now I only have to do angular-side of redirection on certain occasion when say, there is 401 access forbidden situation detected, ex server restarted.